# How to retrieve body form-data in key value pair and use it in postman test script

Tags: testing, postman

[request body form-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGlGn.jpg)

I tried the following but didnot work
pm.request.body.data

pm.request.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access this format

```
pm.request.body.formdata.get("name")
pm.request.body.formdata.get("last_name")
pm.request.body.formdata.get("other_name")
```

Documentation in [here](https://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/RequestBody.html)

```
formdata :PropertyList.<FormParam>
Form data parameters for this request are held in this field.

Type:
PropertyList.<FormParam>
```

[image]

Usage in `Tests` tab.

[image]